# Can not print properly a quicksort arranged matrix

Tags: c, quicksort

I can not properly print the steps given by the quicksort algorithm. This function works when N=1, which means that the values in the matrix only repeat once, but for N>1 it does not print it properly.

This is for a program I am writing to represent the different sorting algorithms steps with the console.

```c
void quicksort(int *target, int left, int right) {

   char charac[MAX*N][MAX]; // this is the array I am going to print on screen

    if(left >= right)
        return;

    int i = left, j = right;     
    int tmp, pivot = target[i];
    for(;;) {

        while(target[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while(pivot < target[j])
            j--;

        if(i >= j)
            break;

        tmp = target[i]; 
        target[i] = target[j]; 
        target[j] = tmp;

        i++; j--; //normal quicksort until here

        for(int k=0;k<MAX*N;k++){ /*Here begin two loops that put the cursor on a certain point on the screen and then gives values to char[][]*/

            GotoXY(k+30,5);
            for(int l=0;l<MAX;l++){
                If(l<target[k]) // if the value of the given vector is lower than l writes a space
                    charac[k][l]=32;
                 else
                     charac [k][l]=219; // else a block
                 printf("%c ",charac[k][l]); // print the block or space
                 GotoXY(k+35,5+l); // go to the next point of the column
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        system("cls"); // clear the screen for the next graph
    }
    quicksort(target, left, i-1);
    quicksort(target, j+1, right);
}
```

I expect to sort the values properly even if they are repeated but the result are not even close to that.

Here it is for N=1 at the beginning:

[image]

At the end:

[image]

With N=2 it is generated properly:

[image]

But this is the result:

[image]

It is not even close to something fine.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Sorry, it is now done

Comment: `char[MAX*N][MAX];` does not declare an array. Post your actual code. Also a VLA is not initialized. If you iterate beyond where you have assigned values, you invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Even with the declared array it does not work. What is  VLA? And should I write the rest of the code?

Comment: Whats is defined by `MAX` and `N`, are they related to size of `target` array and limits of maximum value across all elements in `target` array?

Comment: Yes, MAX is the size of the original vector. Then it is duplicated, added to itself and you have an array size MAX*N. i.e.:MAX=5, vector={2,4,5,1,3}, target[MAX*N]={2,4,1,3,3,5,4,5,1,2}, for N=2.